# ListSliceContourPlot3D (and related) won't plot data

Tags: plotting

I have a sparse dataset that ListSliceContourPlot3D (new in 10.2) will render with no problems. However, a related dataset (with more values) yields an empty cube. I can't trace the source of the problem. Can anyone with experience with 3D data help me sort this out?

The working set is:

```
data1= {{11.1111, 33.3333, 11.1111, 0.019953}, {11.1111, 55.5556, 11.1111, 
  0.045622}, {22.2222, 44.4444, 22.2222, 0.0314444}, {33.3333, 
  33.3333, 33.3333, 0.019994}, {11.1111, 33.3333, 33.3333, 
  0.0135226}, {22.2222, 22.2222, 22.2222, 0.00844625}, {33.3333, 
  33.3333, 11.1111, 0.00975875}, {33.3333, 11.1111, 33.3333, 
0.003821}, {0., 44.4444, 22.2222, 0.01981}, {22.2222, 44.4444, 0., 
0.019736}, {44.4444, 22.2222, 22.2222, 0.00683343}, {22.2222, 
22.2222, 44.4444, 0.00686686}, {22.2222, 22.2222, 0., 
0.002673}, {0., 22.2222, 22.2222, 0.001762}, {44.4444, 22.2222, 0., 
0.00098}, {0., 22.2222, 44.4444, 0.000885}, {33.3333, 11.1111, 
11.1111, 0.000103}, {11.1111, 11.1111, 33.3333, 
0.00006075}, {55.5556, 11.1111, 11.1111, 0.000076}, {11.1111, 
11.1111, 55.5556, 0.00004}, {11.1111, 11.1111, 11.1111, 
0.000013}, {44.4444, 0., 22.2222, 7.*10^-6}, {22.2222, 0., 44.4444, 
3.*10^-6}, {22.2222, 0., 22.2222, 1.*10^-6}};

ListSliceContourPlot3D[data1]
```

And the bad set is :

```
data2 = {{0., 33.3333, 16.6667, 0.0022862}, {16.6667, 50., 16.6667, 
  0.00472137}, {16.6667, 33.3333, 16.6667, 0.00124723}, {25., 41.6667,
 25., 0.00278802}, {33.3333, 33.3333, 33.3333, 0.001861}, {8.33333, 
58.3333, 8.33333, 0.007589}, {16.6667, 33.3333, 0., 
0.001625}, {8.33333, 41.6667, 8.33333, 0.00197133}, {25., 25., 25., 
0.000623621}, {0., 33.3333, 33.3333, 0.00118789}, {8.33333, 41.6667,
 25., 0.00167741}, {16.6667, 33.3333, 33.3333, 
0.00103771}, {33.3333, 16.6667, 33.3333, 0.000320253}, {8.33333, 
25., 25., 0.000316056}, {33.3333, 33.3333, 16.6667, 
0.000852542}, {25., 41.6667, 8.33333, 0.00141607}, {0., 50., 
16.6667, 0.0024895}, {16.6667, 50., 0., 0.0027635}, {33.3333, 
33.3333, 0., 0.000653889}, {25., 25., 41.6667, 
0.000569354}, {41.6667, 25., 25., 0.000565729}, {25., 25., 8.33333, 
0.000277648}, {8.33333, 25., 41.6667, 0.000202593}, {16.6667, 
16.6667, 33.3333, 0.0000738947}, {41.6667, 25., 8.33333, 
0.000159852}, {8.33333, 25., 8.33333, 0.000257444}, {33.3333, 
16.6667, 16.6667, 0.0000741875}, {50., 16.6667, 16.6667, 
0.000102263}, {16.6667, 16.6667, 50., 0.0000766316}, {16.6667, 
16.6667, 16.6667, 0.0000538644}, {41.6667, 8.33333, 25., 
0.000020037}, {25., 8.33333, 41.6667, 0.0000132963}, {25., 8.33333, 
25., 8.46296*10^-6}, {33.3333, 0., 33.3333, 
5.22222*10^-6}, {16.6667, 16.6667, 0., 3.*10^-6}, {0., 16.6667, 
16.6667, 1.5*10^-6}, {33.3333, 16.6667, 0., 8.*10^-7}, {0., 16.6667,
 33.3333, 2.*10^-7}, {50., 16.6667, 0., 5.*10^-7}, {0., 16.6667, 
50., 0.}, {25., 8.33333, 8.33333, 0.}, {41.6667, 8.33333, 8.33333, 
0.}, {8.33333, 8.33333, 25., 0.}, {8.33333, 8.33333, 41.6667, 
0.}, {58.3333, 8.33333, 8.33333, 0.}, {8.33333, 8.33333, 58.3333, 
0.}, {33.3333, 0., 16.6667, 0.}, {16.6667, 0., 33.3333, 0.}, {50., 
0., 16.6667, 0.}, {8.33333, 8.33333, 8.33333, 0.}, {16.6667, 0., 
50., 0.}, {16.6667, 0., 16.6667, 0.}}
```

Comment: Looks fine for me (v10.2; windows 8.1)

Comment: Worked on v10.2 with Mac OS 10.10.5

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem the user is experiencing can not be reproduced by others.

Comment: Thanks for trying this out, guys, hearing that they work was actually helpful. The copied-and-pasted datasets both work fine for me, too. This prompted me to just try Round[%,10^-5] on the original, uncopied data, which Mathematica was able to plot. Strange, but good to see it work.

Comment: Then the problem might have been very small imaginary components that disappeared with `Round`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me (Mathematica 10.02, Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS)
[image]